# Applets on JAVA

Tags: java, applet, jsp

Проблема при подключении аплета на JSP страницу.
Страница открывается, там где должно быть отображение аплета: выдается ошибка, что не находится класс с аплетом, но полный путь указан на него и имя правильное.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Codebase` класса апплета должен задаваться относительно корня вашего веб-сервера, а не относительно пути файловой системы сервера.

В общем должно быть что-то типа `CODEBASE=http://www.mydomain.com/applet/code`